# Create local variable with java annotation

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

How does @Slf4j expose a the local variable log for use? Looking at the source code shows no hints.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Slf4j {
    String topic() default "";
}
```

Comment: What source code were you looking at? Lombok would be here - https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok You're looking for the delombok functions that write the source files

Comment: Can you link to documentation?

Comment: @OneCricketeer so it changes the source files at compile time?

Comment: No, before compile-time. https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok

Comment: Lombok is an annotation processor and it modifies the abstract syntax tree of the source code while it is being compiled. What you're looking at is only the source code for the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// m() method wont compile at run time
// compile time no output it shown
// when run at directly n() method will produce as output 

class Sampleanote
 {
   void m()
    {
        System.out.println("sample annotation at complile");
     }

 @Deprecated
 void n()
    {
        System.out.println("run time annotation  ");
     }
 }

 class Annote
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
      {

         Sampleanote a=new Sampleanote();
         a.n();   //at run time it produce output
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).